# Generated T4 Files Not Added to Project from Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, t4, vs-extensibility

I am trying to generate code scaffolding for an in-house API.  I created a T4 template which includes several other templates for each code file to be generated. I then wrote a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) with a WPF form to capture user input and initiate the transforming of the T4 template. I am doing all of this in Visual Studio Professional 2013.

This is what I followed to Invoke the Text Transformation in a VS Extension
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586947%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

When testing the templates locally using Run custom tool, everything works perfectly.  However, when testing the VS extension in an Experimental Instance of Visual Studio, the problem I am having is that after the transformation has been invoked [calling ITextTemplating.ProcessTemplate], the generated files are not placed into my open project.  I verified that they exist in their appropriate folders in File Explorer.

I have searched high & low and can't find anything that talks about this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The custom tool is using the Visual Studio API (DTE object) to add the generated files to the projects.  I built something very [similar](https://www.t4awesome.com/) and that is what I had to do.  This [project](http://scaffoldit.codeplex.com/) is a bit old but it is a great starting point for seeing how this can be done.

Basically you need to get a reference to the folder you want to add the new item to and then call [AddFromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.aspx).  Also don't forget to [save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.save.aspx) the project after you add all the items.